# Facebook Connect with ASP.NET using Facebook Toolkit

Tags: asp.net, facebook

I have done the following steps here http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/How_Connect_Authentication_Works but I'm stuck at number 8. I've added the DLL's but for some reason this line:

```
API api = new API();
```

always comes up with this error:

> Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The
>   type or namespace name 'API' could not
>   be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

I am actually almost done with the article in DEVTACULAR and its pre-requisites. But somehow I am stuck with this problem.

Need help badly. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to import Facebook.Session by putting the following at the top of your class:

```
using Facebook.Session;
```

You could also just use the fully qualified name like:

```
Facebook.Session.Api api = new Facebook.Session.API();
```